# How to access data from OBD in iOS Application

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to access car data from an OBD2 device so I can access car speed, RPM speed, fuel consumption, live data, error codes, etc. How can I connect and read from an OBD2 device in iOS?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on OBD device you are going to use.
There are devices on WiFi, accesible by IP-address (using TCP or UDP protocol), by bluetooth, works like RS-232 port, and some other devices, which can directly be connected by cable.

Answer (score 2):

I have recently open sourced my OBD2 library for iOS & macOS that abstracts the transport protocol (WiFi, BTLE, CaptureFile), vehicle protocol (CAN, KWP, PWM, ...) and more into a set of reusable classes. Check out https://github.com/mickeyl/LTSupportAutomotive which might help you creating an own OBD2 application.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend going through the [stream programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/NetworkStreams.html) on the iOS developer library as this has code that does exactly what needs to be done for talking to a ELM wifi device.

It's really not much more than that, be sure you have the right IP and Port when connecting.